# TomEE, CXF and Jackson - No message body writer has been found for response class

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs, apache-tomee

Trying to get into TomEE, and having some difficulties getting a JSON-producing JAX-RS resource up and running.

Using tomee-maven-plugin to start TomEE:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.openejb.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <tomeeVersion>1.6.0.2</tomeeVersion>
                <tomeeClassifier>plus</tomeeClassifier>
                <config>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</config>
                <libs>
                    <lib>mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.31</lib>
                    <lib>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:${jackson-version}</lib>
                    <lib>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:${jackson-version}</lib>
                    <lib>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:${jackson-version}</lib>
                    <lib>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:${jackson-version}</lib>
                    <lib>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:${jackson-version}</lib>
                </libs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

system.properties:

```
openejb.cxf.jax-rs.providers = com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider, com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
```

Unfortunately upon doing requests I still seem to get:

```
WARNING: No message body writer has been found for response class Server
```

Using a simple JAX-RS method:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Server find(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @PathParam("id") int id) {
    return repository.findOrNull(id);
}
```

where the 'Server' class is just a simple JPA Entity / Bean.

I'm probably missing something silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out @XmlRootElement was required with CXF. I only had experience with Jersey as a JSON mapper.